# Configure a VM on Windows Server 2012 R2 Hyper-V to Use External Static IP and Connected to Domain Network

Tags: hyper-v-server-2012-r2

Is it possible to configure a virtual machine on Windows Server 2012 R2 Hyper-V to use a static IP from the ISP as well as being on the domain's subnet at the same time with the ethernet dual port adapters on the physical server? If so,

1. How should the adapters be configured on the physical server?
2. How should Virtual Switches be configured through the Virtual Switch Manager in Hyper-V Manager?
3. How should the adapters be configured on the virtual machine?

Comment: What problems did you run in ? At a first glance, this should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: 4 questions. To answser the first 1: yes. And 1-3: RTFM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static IP from the ISP? Yes - talk to your network guys, you will probably need to use NAT (Network Address Translation)

1 - At least 1 NIC for the external network.
2 - Create a new virtual switch and bind it to the NIC in (1)
3 - Get the NIC of the VM hooked to the virtual switch in (2)